# Android notifyDataSetChanged works only after refreshing activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, notifydatasetchanged

notifyDataSetChanged in my application only works after refreshing the activity (Exit from it and open it again).

I don't know why, I have tried several ways to do it, but I didn't success.

My codes are:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(Questions, MODE_PRIVATE);

    int id = i.getExtras().getInt("id"); // get id
    if(pref.getBoolean("answered"+id, true)){ // if item answered
        imgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // change if answered - works only after refreshing
        completed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Correct);
        Correct= pref.getInt("Correct", 0); 
        completed.setText("Finished: " + Correct + "/5"); // Works fine

        }

}
```

This happend after adding "onActivityResult(position, position, intent);" (before adding it it wasn't working even if activity has been refreshed)

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Question.this, Answer.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", position);
                onActivityResult(position, position, intent); // to pass id
                startActivityForResult(intent, position);
}
```

Adapter

```
public class ImgAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ColorMatrixColorFilter cf;


    public ImgAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
        matrix.setSaturation(0);
        cf = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(80, 80));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        if(Question.items.get(position).answered){
            imageView.setColorFilter(cf);
            imageView.setAlpha(175);
        }

        return imageView;
    }

    public static Integer[] mThumbIds = 
    {
        R.drawable.question1,
        R.drawable.question2,
        R.drawable.question3,
        R.drawable.question4,
        R.drawable.question5,
    };

}
```

Comment: Post your adapter too.

Comment: Update your data model for your adapter as well..updating pref data will not affect the adapter. You need to update the data that is being used by the adapter and then call `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

Comment: @RushabhPatel is correct, you should make a collection of your `Questions` from `prefs` which you then pass to your `ImgAdapter`. When you notice a change in `prefs`, update the `Questions` collection and call `imgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. There is no link between your prefs and the `imgAdapter` which can be used for a refresh.

Comment: where are you updating Question.items.get(position).answered?

Comment: @vipulmittal Oh, I forgot to change it to shared preferences, however can someone show me how to make SharedPreferences works in base adapter?

Comment: Check my answer. Not sure this is what you want though.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your code inside the `onActivityResult()` method into the `onItemClick()` method. Additionally, you will want to make sure your data set (e.g., whatever is represented by `Question.items`) is updated before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ImgAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ColorMatrixColorFilter cf;
    private int answered=-1;

    public ImgAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
        matrix.setSaturation(0);
        cf = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(80, 80));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        if(position==answered){
            imageView.setColorFilter(cf);
            imageView.setAlpha(175);
        }

        return imageView;
    }

    public static Integer[] mThumbIds = 
    {
        R.drawable.question1,
        R.drawable.question2,
        R.drawable.question3,
        R.drawable.question4,
        R.drawable.question5,
    };
    public void setAnswered(int answered){
    this.answered=answered; 
   }
}
```

And

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(Questions, MODE_PRIVATE);

    int id = i.getExtras().getInt("id"); // get id
    if(pref.getBoolean("answered"+id, true)){ // if item answered

        completed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Correct);
        Correct= pref.getInt("Correct", 0); 
        imgAdapter.setAnswered(Correct);
        imgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // change if answered - works only after refreshing
        completed.setText("Finished: " + Correct + "/5"); // Works fine

        }

}
```

Comment: Now it only change for one picture